# Android Room Persistence Library not working inside library project

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm developing an Android library, and want to use the new Android Room persistence library inside it. However, when launching I got this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
MyLibraryName.Database.QSDatabase. QSDatabase_Impl does not exist
at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:90)
```

which means that the **annotationProcessor** is not generating the extra code during compilation.

Btw, everything is working fine when I put my *@Database* code inside the app module.

My gradle file (library module) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy'] } }
}

dependencies {
// google Room persistence library
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
// google location service
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Http
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
// groovy
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.4'
}
```

Comment: In my case it's working.
Double check may be you forgot something.

Comment: I was rechecking, and finally the issue seems to be linked with the use of groovy. The annotation processor is not getting called when I put my code under groovy/ directory. I dont know how to fix it.
    `|____app
     | |____build.gradle
     | |____src
     | | |____main
     | | | |____java
     |____MyLibraryName
     | |____build.gradle
     | |____src
     | | |____main
     | | | |____groovy   <= not working if code is put under groovy/ 
     | | | |____java <= working if code put under java/`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you use `annotationProcessor` in a kotlin project.
if so, do these

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`

Comment: Yes, it works for me. This way makes Room work if we put the code inside library module.

Answer (score -1):

@stevenwood It seems you're right about groovy/

I had the same project structure. But in my case, I had no real Groovy code inside groovy/. Only plain old Java code. Hence, perhaps it was easier for me to get the project working again by making the following changes

Removing / commenting-out `classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.8' from the project's build.gradle`

Removing / commenting-out `apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android' from the module's build.gradle`

`git mv groovy/ java/`

Thereafter at least, I stopped getting the `missing Database_Impl` message from Room.