# Using Room DB in library project

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to integrate room DB in a library project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
.
.
.
.
.
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"

annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

When I use this library inside my app and try to access Room DB, it always crashes and give me following exception

```
Android room persistent: AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

However when I use room DB directly in my application it works fine.
Is there any limitation in using room DB inside library project?

Comment: I've found that you need to import the room runtime from the app. Did you find a better way to do it? Do we have to include room-runtime in the library?

Comment: We need to add room at app level dependency so that it generates compiled files.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859517/3144323

Comment: I moved my implementation to implement room at app level. Generally it is not a good practice to implement room inside library.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limitation in using room DB inside library project?

Not really. You can add room dependency in your library project and still use it in your app.

The only change you need to do is to add the following in your app module's `build.gradle` file

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

The problem is, unlike `compile` or `api` dependencies, `annotationProcessor` is not transitive. That means, the annotation processor is applicable only in the module where it is added.

annotationProcessor is responsible to generate your `AppDatabase_Impl` class but it is not available in your app module. So, that is the reason why it is not being generated.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of uninstall your app into device and emulator.

Then flow below step to room db.
add below dependecy into app level gradle file.

```
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

than make app level activity like below ..

```
public class AppActivity extends Application {

static AppDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
}

public static AppDatabase getDatabase() {
    return db;
}
```

}

then make app database..

```
@Database(entities = {MyTable.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract MyTableDao getTableDao();
}
```

Dao ..

```
@Dao
public interface MyTableDao {
@Insert
void insertData(MyTable myTable);
@Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable ")
List<MyTable> getData();

}
```

then also define app activity into android manifest file in to application tag.

```
        android:name=".AppActivity"
```

Comment: I know all these steps :). My question was is there any limitation if we put room dependencies in a library project and use that library project inside our app.