# Publishing a library that uses room without exposing room

Tags: android, android-room

I have created a library that internally uses Room. I export the library in a maven repo to be used by the apps.
The problem is that even if Room is used only by internal classes in the library, I still need to import the room-runtime library from the app otherwise I get a runtime exception because the loader can't find the RoomDatabase class.

Do I have to export the room runtime in my maven repo?

I found [Using Room DB in library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508318/using-room-db-in-library-project) but there is no answer and it is not exactly the same issue.

Comment: Could you please add your build.gradle file `dependencies{}` block code?

Comment: @BirjuVachhani Thank you. I could post the `build.gradle` but I'm afraid it wouldn't tell you very much. What I can tell you is that I have imported the room libraries using `implementation`